# Handle the macro pop up while opening Excel File using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, excel, vba

I am trying to open an excel file using C#.

When i ran the code of opening the excel. It gives a pop up of enabling macro. But the
excel i am trying to open has nothing to do with macro.

I want to open the file through the code without getting macro enable.

[image: This is the pop up im getting while opening the excel through c#]

This is the pop up im getting while opening the excel through c#

Comment: how are you opening it through C# ?. you should add a code sample.

Comment: This message is definitly no Excel message nor is it from C# directly. It must come from a macro in an Excel file. Microsoft would not write the word `Unfreeze` nor would it write it in capital letters, nor would it have a space between the question mark and the word before which causes an odd line break. This message is definitly user scripted content.

Comment: You do it by using the AutomationSecurity property of the Excel Application: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.automationsecurity